# zend paginator to empty array how to handle

Tags: php, zend-framework

this is my code:

```
$message = $mapper->getByReceiverId($currentUser["id"]);

    $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($message);
```

how to handle if $message is null (no records in database) ?

im getting error:

```
    Message:
"No adapter for type NULL"
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$message = $mapper->getByReceiverId($currentUser["id"]);
if (!$message){//or $message === null, depends on what GetByReciever() returns
    $paginator = null;
} else { 
    $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($message);
}
```

you could also put an if() in your model method, something like:

```
if ($result){
    return $result;
} else {
    return array();
}
```

returning an empty array() should at least provide a valid adapter for $paginator.
It might be better if you initialized the paginator adapter in your model:

```
public function someThingPaginatorAdapter() {

    $this->select();
    //build your select() query

    $adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect($select);

    return $adapter;
```

this way those methods that need pagination will have it built into the query and you won't have to worry about what it's returning.